# How to get the sum of number by group if the tables are big

Tags: sql

I want to sum (aggregate) money spent by household.

I have 2 tables.

- Member table (member_id, money_spend)
- Household table (household_id, member_id, sum_of_money_spent_by_household)

  - relationship of household and member, a household has many members, but a member belongs to one household.

I want to get household_id, and  order by the sum amount.

Both tables are very big, and member table is twice big. How should I sum the number and group by would be faster?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Someone with your level of reputation should know not to put irrelevant tags on a question.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  In addition, sample data and desired results would help others understand the question.

Comment: `mysql`, `sql-server`, `postgresql` and `sqlite`??? You're clearly confused here, those are all completely different products. You have enough reputation to know how to tag correctly. :)

Comment: Are there multiple rows per member_id? How many rows are *big*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you need simple `LEFT JOIN` with grouping and summing.

```
select h.household_id, coalesce(sum(m.money_spend),0) as sum_of_money_spent
from household h
left join member m on h.member_id = m.member_id
group by h.household_id
```

Though, reading through your relation description if household has many members, but each member has only one household **we have 1:N relationship** and you should hold `household_id` value within the `member` table.

It seems like you've implemented the N:N relationship with an associative entity between for no reason if I understand you correctly and there is one more table which actually holds information about each of the household.

Notice, that with proper data architecture you'd have all the information you need within one table and there would be no need for additional joins unless you'd want to pull out some details about each household like their address.

Answer (score 2):

I think `GROUP BY` is the sensible option to go by here, but, there isn't much room for optimization:

```
SELECT
    h.household_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(m.money_spend), 0) AS total
FROM Household h
LEFT JOIN Member m
    ON h.member_id = m.member_id
GROUP BY
    h.household_id;
```

I didn't really feel like typing out that query, but I did it only to point out that the aggregation really needs to potentially touch every record in both the `Household` and `Member` tables.  The reason for this is that we don't know a household's total spend until we have tallied every member, and therefore every member record.

Because we are doing a left join from `Household`, we are scanning this table, and an index on the `member_id` join column should not make much difference.  Similarly, `member_id` is probably a primary key, and indexed, in the `Member` table.  So I would not expect an index to help in the join, and also an index should not make much difference in the aggregation.